# xdegug cannot step to next line in php view

Tags: php, xdebug

I am using Eclipse for PHP Luna Service Release 1 (4.4.1), and try to install xdebug for debugging. I follow [this blog](http://docs.joomla.org/Edit_PHP.INI_File_for_XDebug) for for setting xdebug on xampp 1.8.1. Follow is my php.ini settings.

```
[XDebug]
zend_extension = "C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug.dll"
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_handler = "dbgp"
```

Basically it will stop on the break point i set, but then i press [F6], it will not go to next line.

But in debug dialog window, line number keep going, and variables also change too.

Does anyone knows what wrong on this? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this seems to be a bug, I hit it after updating.

It does step to the next line though, it just doesn't update the highlight and current position.

Over the last few years I've experienced quite a few of such annoying bugs in Eclipse IDE for PHP Developers (PDT) with official updates. One might get the impression that the developers don't pay much attention to regression testing.

**Solution:**

If you've updated Eclipse recently, open "Help" -> "Installation Details". Click on the tab "Installation History" and find an entry that doesn't contain version 4.4.1 (it's 4.4.0.20140612-0500 here).

The Eclipse project page is a bit messy in my opinion (or I'm just blind), but you can fortunately crawl a mirror site to find older releases:

http://ftp.yz.yamagata-u.ac.jp/pub/eclipse/technology/epp/downloads/release/luna/R/

Comment: Tanks a lot for kindly spending time for my little confuse.   Its great to get help form enthusiasm to know I'm not alone.   Thanks again.

Answer (score 4):

I think I found a bug report on this issue:

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=445903

It's marked as solved, so maybe on the next release this issue should be gone.

**EDIT**: updating PDT to version 3.3.2 http://download.eclipse.org/tools/pdt/updates/3.3.2/ solves this issue (at least in my install)

Comment: Upgrade PDT Here https://eclipse.org/pdt/
Eclipse > Help > Install New Software > Work with: http://download.eclipse.org/tools/pdt/updates/3.3.2

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem, where the stepping through the code would not go to the next line. I realized that the problem was that the remote php script which I was debugging, had a line of code which was not present in the local php script in Eclipse. Updating the local php script to match the remote php script fixed the problem.